# ios 7 UIView animateWithDuration: .. runs immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiview, uianimation

I have trouble with method for animation

I've created my own CalloutBubble for GoogleMap

```
@interface CalloutView : UIView
@property (nonatomic) MapMarker *marker;
@end

@implementation {   
    UIView *titleView;
    UILabel *titleLabel, *addressLabel;
}

//another init methods aren't shown

- (void)setMarker:(MapMarker *)marker
{
    _marker = marker;
    titleLabel.text = marker.university.name;
    addressLabel.text = marker.university.address;
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    titleLabel.minX = 0;
    [titleLabel.layer removeAllAnimations];
    if (titleLabel.width > titleView.width)
        [self runningLabel];
}

- (void)runningLabel
{
    CGFloat timeInterval = titleLabel.width / 70;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:timeInterval delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
            titleLabel.minX = -titleLabel.width;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            titleLabel.minX = titleView.width;
            [self runningLabel];
        }];
}

@end
```

In my viewController I create property

```
@implementation MapVC {
    CalloutView *calloutView;
}
```

And then if I try create calloutView in any method all work fine with animation, but if I return view in Google map method

```
- (UIView *)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView markerInfoWindow:(GMSMarker *)marker
{
    if (!calloutView)
        calloutView = [[CalloutView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 265, 45.5)];
    calloutView.marker = (MapMarker *)marker;
    return calloutView;
}
```

My animation run immediately in calloutView, and completion called immediately too, and call `runningLabel` method again, So it is not work like it have to. All frame is good, and `timInterval` always more than 4 second. I tried to write static timeinterval like 10.0, but animation again run immediately, and flag `finished` in completion block always YES. So it called more than 100 times in one second =(

I create app in iOS 7. I tried to use different options for animation:

```
UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews           
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction     
UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState    
UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat                   
UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse              
UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration 
UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedCurve   
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent     
UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews 
UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions
```

but there are no results.

What wrong in this Google map method, why my animation run immediately?

PS minX, width - my categories. minX set frame.origin.X . There are all good with this categories.

Comment: Add NSLog("%f",timeInterval) after CGFloat timeInterval = titleLabel.width / 70;. see the output.

Comment: @Rashad, did you read my post? I wrote that timeInterval ALWAYS more than 4 second, and I tried to use static seconds, for eample 10.0, but there are no results

Answer (score 1):

Remove UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat option Or comment the completion Block minX setting:

```
- (void)runningLabel
{
    CGFloat timeInterval = titleLabel.width / 70;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:timeInterval delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
            titleLabel.minX = -titleLabel.width;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            //titleLabel.minX = titleView.width; //this is the problem, you should not set minX again while  UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat also is animation option
            [self runningLabel];
        }];
}
```